# Copy vector to clipboard

Tags: c++, string, windows, file, vector

Hi my goal is to take each line from `input.txt` load them into a vector and then copy each vector to the clipboard every 1 second.

So far I am able to load the file into a vector using `getFileContent(std::string fileName, std::vector<std::string> & vecOfStrs)`

I am also able to copy a string to the clipboard if I replace:

```
cout << "Lines Copying " << endl;
```

with

```
cout << "Please enter sentence: "; cin >> AAA;
```

Using the users input...

---

However, when I try to load the vector called `line` I get `0 char(s)` copied to clipboard?

What am I doing wrong? Any pointers or suggestions will be greatly appreciated..

**Using:**

```
Windows 10 64x
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015
Version 14.0.23107.0 D14REL
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.7.02046

Visual C++ 2015   00322-20000-00000-AA355
Microsoft Visual C++ 2015
```

**input.txt:**

```
The
Brown
Fox
Jumps
```

**Script:**

```
// copyfilelines.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <direct.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <winuser.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <complex>

void toClipboard(HWND hwnd, const std::string &s);

    /*
    * It will iterate through all the lines in file and
    * put them in given vector then copy vector to clipboard.
    */

    //1. Open file and put each line into a vector.
    bool getFileContent(std::string fileName, std::vector<std::string> & vecOfStrs)
    {

        // Open the File
        std::ifstream in(fileName.c_str());

        // Check if object is valid.
        if (!in)
        {
            std::cerr << "Cannot open the File : " << fileName << std::endl;
            return false;

        }

        std::string str;
        // Read the next line from File untill it reaches the end.
        while (std::getline(in, str))
        {
            // Line contains string of length > 0 then save it in vector.
            if (str.size() > 0)
                vecOfStrs.push_back(str);
        }
        // Close The File.
        in.close();

        return true;

    }


    //2. Declare clipboard functions at file scope.
    void toClipboard(HWND hwnd, const std::string &s) {
        OpenClipboard(hwnd);
        EmptyClipboard();
        HGLOBAL hg = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, s.size() + 1);
        if (!hg) {
            CloseClipboard();
            return;
        }
        memcpy(GlobalLock(hg), s.c_str(), s.size() + 1);
        GlobalUnlock(hg);
        SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hg);
        CloseClipboard();
        GlobalFree(hg);
    }



int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> vecOfStr;
    // Get the contents of file in a vector.
    bool result = getFileContent("input.txt", vecOfStr);
    if (result)
    {
        // Print the vector contents.
        for (std::string & line : vecOfStr)
            std::cout << line << std::endl;

        // Copy vector to clipboard.
        using namespace std;
        string line;
        cout << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Lines Copying " << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Lines Copied To The Clipboard: ";
        cout << endl;
        cout << line << endl;
        // 1. Strlen takes a const char*, so have to call the strings c_str() method
        // (but it would be better to use len = line.length() instead)
        size_t len = strlen(line.c_str());
        cout << len << " char(s)" << endl;
        // Get desktop windows and the call toClipboard.
        HWND hwnd = GetDesktopWindow();
        toClipboard(hwnd, line);
        //User input processing.
        //cin.clear();
        //cin.ignore(255, '\n');
        //cin.get();
    }

   return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**

**Updated script**

I added a `std::ostream_iterator` to allow streaming of a vector:

```
std::stringstream ss;
// Populate
std::copy(vecOfStr.begin(), vecOfStr.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(ss, "\n"));
// Display
std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
// Copy vector to clipboard.
size_t len = strlen(ss.str().c_str());
```

**Full Updated Script:**

Streams content of `input.txt` and copies all streamed content to clipboard.

```
// copyfilelines.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <direct.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <winuser.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>

void toClipboard(HWND hwnd, const std::string &s);

/*
* It will iterate through all the lines in file and
* put them in given vector then copy vector to clipboard.
*/

//1. Open file and put each line into a vector.
bool getFileContent(std::string fileName, std::vector<std::string> & vecOfStrs)
{

    // Open the File
    std::ifstream in(fileName.c_str());

    // Check if object is valid.
    if (!in)
    {
        std::cerr << "Cannot open the File : " << fileName << std::endl;
        return false;

    }

    std::string str;
    // Read the next line from File untill it reaches the end.
    while (std::getline(in, str))
    {
        // Line contains string of length > 0 then save it in vector.
        if (str.size() > 0)
            vecOfStrs.push_back(str);
    }
    // Close The File.
    in.close();

    return true;

}


//2. Declare clipboard functions at file scope.
void toClipboard(HWND hwnd, const std::string &s) {
    OpenClipboard(hwnd);
    EmptyClipboard();
    HGLOBAL hg = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, s.size() + 1);
    if (!hg) {
        CloseClipboard();
        return;
    }
    memcpy(GlobalLock(hg), s.c_str(), s.size() + 1);
    GlobalUnlock(hg);
    SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hg);
    CloseClipboard();
    GlobalFree(hg);
}



int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> vecOfStr;
    // Get the contents of file in a vector.
    bool result = getFileContent("input.txt", vecOfStr);
    if (result)
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        // Populate
        std::copy(vecOfStr.begin(), vecOfStr.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(ss, "\n"));
        // Display
        std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
        // Copy vector to clipboard.
        size_t len = strlen(ss.str().c_str());
        // Get desktop windows and the call toClipboard.
        HWND hwnd = GetDesktopWindow();
        toClipboard(hwnd, ss.str());
        Sleep(100000);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ups - sorry. it seemed as though you removed the original and replaced it all. I rolled it back again. Sorry for the confusion, it's all good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring all the irrelevant printing to `cout`, your code is:

```
    if (result)
    {
        // Copy vector to clipboard.
        using namespace std;
        string line;
        size_t len = strlen(line.c_str());
        // Get desktop windows and the call toClipboard.
        HWND hwnd = GetDesktopWindow();
        toClipboard(hwnd, line);
    }
```

You have a default constructed `string` called `line`, and you copy that to the clipboard.  Not surprisingly, it contains no characters.  I think you need to create a `stringstream` and print the vector to that, and then copy *that* to the clipboard.

Comment: I have another quick question. 

How could I stream one line in `input.txt` at a time?

E.g: 
stream `The`  copy to clipboard and wait 1s, then stream `Brown` copy to clipboard and wait 1s ..... and so on?

Comment: @MALKAVIAN the question may be quick but the answer probably isn't. I believe you could ask that as a new question.

Comment: @MALKAVIAN: Exactly how you describe it. Programming is writing down a series of steps. You've got each step defined, so all that's left is putting it into C++. You may want to look at `std::this_thread::sleep_for()`